Spring @EntityListeners @PreUpdate not calle on ElementCollection update
The @PreUpdate method is never called when the element collection is updated
example:
@EntityListeners(CardEntityListener.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "cards"})
public class Card {

   @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JsonProperty(value = "images")
   @Column(length = 256)
   private final List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

}



@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CardEntityListener {
 

   @PrePersist
   @PreUpdate
   private void log(@NonNull final Card transientCardData) {
       System.out.println("log");
   }
}

if i do
Card c = new Card();
c = repository.save(c);
c.images.add("one");
repository.save(c);

data wise the method works... it creates a card, later adds a new string to the relationship
but on the  EntityListeners side the log method is only called once...
is it by design? is there a proper approach to make the entitylistener fire on these relationships update?

This is a Hibernate design issue, not a JPA one as most (all?) other JPA providers went the other way: https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/issues/167
Seems with some targeting this issue to JPA 4, maybe hibernate will fix it - you can always switch providers if needed

It is by design. You relation is annotated with @ElementCollection and as such is not managed by Hibernate (JPA). It is not an entity hence the EntityListener will not be triggered.
Solution 1
Define a separate entity for your images and use @OneToMany instead.
Solution 2
Store the list of images as a plain text or JSON string. For this to work you will need to implement an AttributeConverter similar to this:
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ";";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> stringList) {
        return stringList != null ? String.join(SPLIT_CHAR, stringList) : "";
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return string != null ? Arrays.asList(string.split(SPLIT_CHAR)) : emptyList();
    }
}

Based on https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-persist-string-list

You'll get multiple events when doing multiple actions in the collection, and to know the parent they are for, you'll need to put in a back reference and ensure it is fetched already.

It is an interesting idea, but you mention store it as JSON but your code is storing the string as CSV which will cause all sorts of problems when string contains ;

Code example was not for JSON. Just a simple one to demonstrate usage of attribute converter.
